# knockout selected option binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to bind the selected option to a dropwdown in html
but if i changed the model value using the select option automatically the variable changed to object than string

```
<select data-bind="options: Types, selectedOptions: chosenType"></select>

    self.Types = ['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzzz'];

    self.chosenType = ko.observable('xxx');
```

if i changed the value from xxx to yyy using dropdown the chosenType = ['yyy'] where i want to be just a string 'yyy', where i should access the value as chosenType[0]
but service accepts just a string value.
please help me with this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've used `selectedOptions` binding which is used for multi-select lists (hence the array of selected values), you should be using the `value` binding for a single-select list

Docs: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Change your select to:

```
<select data-bind="options: Types, value: chosenType"></select>
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/7J5bL/